# Having trouble finding the CDF of $X+\frac{1}{2}Y$ where $X,Y \sim Expo(\lambda)$ using calculus

Tags: probability

Here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
P(X+\frac{1}{2}Y \leq t) 
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X+\frac{1}{2}y \leq t \mid Y=y)f_Y(y)dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}P(X\leq t - \frac{1}{2}y\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}(1-e^{-\lambda (t-\frac{1}{2}y)}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda y}-\lambda e^{-\lambda t} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda y} \\
&= 1-2e^{-\lambda t}
\end{align}

However, the actual answer is:

$$(1-e^{-\lambda t})^2$$

Did I make a simple mistake or is my method wrong? I tried doing the integral several times and got the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error arises because you have not taken into account that $$\Pr[X \le t - y/2 \mid Y = y] = 0$$ whenever $y > 2t$.  Therefore, the upper limit of integration cannot be $\infty$:  it should be $$\Pr[X + Y/2 \le t] = \int_{y=0}^{2t} \Pr[X \le t - y/2 \mid Y = y]f_Y(y) \, dy.$$